# Android Facebook SDK Can't Add Project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, macos, sdk

I have been following the tutorial found below and am having issues adding the Facebook SDK.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/
```

It occurs when I get to the stage of "Link to the SDK project and configure the Facebook app ID".

When I go to Properties -> Android -> Add and add the FacebookSDK, it seems to work fine. However when I save and close that page, and go back into it, there is a big X against the reference.

I have tried going into project properties and changing it from a relative url to a full url as such:

```
FROM android.library.reference.1=../../facebook
TO android.library.reference.1=/Users/michael/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0/facebook
```

Without this working properly I can't do anything with the Facebook SDK.

I am on Mac OSX and have no idea what else to do in the Eclipse ADT

Answer (score 1):

FacebookSDK project must be on the same part of HDD as the user's project.

For example:
`E:\Facebook Android SDK 3.5` - FacebookSDK project
`E:\Work\Restaurant` - User's project

It works for me on Windows 7. Maybe, it will help you on your OS too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your console. You might have a dependency error with the android support jar. I just had this issue a couple of days ago.  If this is the case you will need to delete the jar out of your main project and copy the android support jar from the facebook SDK into your project.

EDIT: if this isn't the issue let me know, I think I ran into every issue possible implementing Facebook into my app.  I am pretty sure I can help get you connected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, issue resolved. Eclipse was being odd. After restarting the program everything worked correctly.